# How to install Textblob for Python without admin right?

Tags: python, textblob, text-analytics-api

I dont have admin rights so I downloaded Textblob and set the path for it in my prog , Now I am getting error
"Looks like you are missing some required data for this feature.

To download the necessary data, simply run

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora"
```

I cant download this as I dont have admin rights , Any other way to use textblob?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have rights to write to the directory where the data is stored by default?

If that is the case you can probably set the `NLTK_DATA` environment variable as [described in the documentation](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html#installing-upgrading-from-the-pypi) to choose a location that you *do* have the required rights for.

You could try something like this:

```
NLTK_DATA=/home/user/nltk_data python -m textblob.download_corpora
```